# Preheader Inbox View

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, html

Is it possible to display the preheader text in the Inbox view without adding a preheader content block on top of the email template?[image]

Comment: Where would you want to see it?

Comment: In the Inbox view - please see the attached screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the Preheader input box empty in Content Builder and [script it directly in the email/template HTML](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-preview-text-support/). The platform is automatically injecting the preheader value directly after the `<body>` tag.

What I've seen is setting the preheader text programmatically with AMPscript in an init block:

```ampscript
%%[ /* Init */ ]%%
%%[

  set @preheader_text = "Don't miss this offer"

]%%
```

Then in your email/template HTML:

```ampscript
 <body>
   <div style="display: none; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
      %%[/* custom/override default preheader */]%%%%=v(@preheader_text)=%%
      <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"/>
   </div>
   <!-- the rest of HTML -->
```